# Python Iterating over a list

Tags: python

Assign `sum_extra` with the total extra credit received given list `test_grades`. Full credit is 100, so anything over 100 is extra credit. For the given program, `sum_extra` is 8 because 1 + 0 + 7 + 0 is 8. Sample output for the given program:
Sum extra: 8

Forgive me I am a starter on coding and really bad at it!
And this is my code (that is not working) Please help!:

```
test_grades = [101, 83, 107, 90]

sum_extra = -999 # Initialize 0 before your loop

while test_grades > 100:
    test_grades = test_grades - 100
    sum_extra = test_grades[0:3]

for test_grades[0:3] > 100:
    test_grades = test_grades - 100
    sum_extra= test_grade[0] + test_grades[1] + test_grades[2] + test_grades[3]

print('Sum extra:', sum_extra)
```

Which of my two loops would be better for this question and how can i edit them so that they become better? Because i can tell they are not going to work! any help is wanted! thank you! :)

Comment: `Iterating over a list` did you try [google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Python+Iterating+over+a+list)?

Comment: Any help is wanted? Here it is: `sum(grade - 100 for grade in test_grades if grade > 100)`. You might have problems explaining it to your teacher though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop will fail because `test_grades` is of type `list`, so it would not make sense to say `while list < 100`.

an alternative while loop would look like:

```
i = 0;
while i < len(test_grades):
   if test_grades[i] > 100:
      test_grades[i] -= 100
   else:
      test_grades[i] = 0
print sum(test_grades)
```

Your second loop once again will fail because `test_grades[0:3]` is once again of type `list`, and you cannot have for `list < 100`.
See L. M's answer for an alternative.

A `for` loop would be better for this type of question because you are iterating over elements, there is no real 'condition' to check, which would make a while loop better stylistically (they result in the same output).

A 'pythonic' approach would be to use a list comprehension:

```
test_grades = [101, 83, 107, 90]
extra_grades = [grade - 100 for grade in test_grades]
print sum(filter(lambda x: x > 0, extra_grades)) #prints 8
```

Comment: Or even within one line: `reduce(lambda sum_extra, grade: sum_extra+max(grade-100, 0), test_grades, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

```
user_input = input()
test_grades = list(map(int, user_input.split())) # contains test scores

sum_extra = -999 # Initialize 0 before your loop
sum_extra = 0
count = 0

for num in test_grades:
    if num > 100:
        sum_extra += num
        count += 1
sum_extra = sum_extra - (100 * count)
    
print('Sum extra:', sum_extra)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simply you can do**

```
test_grades = [101, 83, 107, 90]

sum_extra = 0 # Initialize 0 before your loop

#iterate over the values of the list
for i in test_grades: 
    if i>100:
            #add extra to the sum extra
        sum_extra=sum_extra+(i-100)

#finally print the extra sum
print('Sum extra:', sum_extra)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
test_grades = [101, 83, 107, 90]

count = 0
for i in test_grades:
    if i-100>0:
        count += (i-100)
print count``
```

which is quite similar to your for loop except for the count

Answer (score 0):

You should understand about the datatypes first.

In your code you are trying to compare a list to an integer, Which is not possible.

Also test_grades[0:3] will do the slicing, which will give you a sublist. So when you do this:

```
sum_extra = test_grades[0:3]
```

sum_extra becomes a list now. I feel you wanted it to remain and integer.

Now consider this line:

```
test_grades = test_grades - 100
```

This line is simply subtracting 100 from the current element of the list. So let's say that the current element is 83. What should be your answer in this case ?

```
83-100 = -17 ?
```

Probably not. So you should first check whether the number is larger than 100, if yes then subtract 100 from it. Something like this:

```
if test_grages[i] > 100:
    sum_extra = test_grades[i] -100 # Dont alter the content of test_grades. You may need to use it further in you code.
```

And you need to loop the above lines of code for every element of the list. So use a loop:

```
i=0 # First element is at 0th index.
while i < len(test_grades):
    if test_grages[i] > 100:
    sum_extra += test_grades[i] -100
    i++
```

Now put this all-together:

```
test_grades = [101, 83, 107, 90]
sum_extra =0 
i=0
while i < len(test_grades): #len() method gives you the length.
    if test_grages[i] > 100:
    sum_extra += test_grades[i] -100
    i++
print(sum_extra)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
user_input = input()
test_grades = list(map(int, user_input.split()))
sum_extra = 0
for num in test_grades:
    if num >100:
        sum_extra+=(num-100)
print('Sum extra:', sum_extra)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = input()
test_grades = list(map(int, user_input.split())) # test_grades is an integer 
list of test scores
sum_extra = 0 # Initialize 0 before your loop

for grade in test_grades:
     if grade > 100:
         num = grade % 100
         sum_extra += num

print('Sum extra:', sum_extra)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).